# big size multi image upload

Tags: php, image-uploading

I built a website in that I upload 10 too big size(10MB) images. When uploading start, it continues to some time then a blank page will come. I tried to change php_values in .htaccess file, because I don't have permission to change the settings in php.ini file (it's shared server). I have some doubts regarding this.

1) what happen if file will going to post request, because I want fastly uploded the files.

2) it takes time when posting the request or uploding the file, I am cropping the images (loop) using php GD functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the limits your web hosting provider set. Which values did you try to change in the .htaccess?

You could try using some flash uploader, it should work despite the limits imposed by the server. A good one is [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/).

Answer (score 1):

That is because of the exection time of a script.
You can edit your **php.ini** file. 
If that is not permitted you can set the ***MAX_EXECUTION_TIME*** for a script using your *.htaccess* file.